# How to set text cursor at beginning of new line after deleting whole line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, atom-editor

In Visual Studio Code you can delete the whole line with `shift` + `command` + `K`. I set it as `cmd` + `backspace` because in Atom I like to delete the whole line that way as it increases my development speed.

However, unlike in Atom where the text cursor automatically goes to the beginning of the next line, in Visual Studio Code the text cursor tries to remember the position it was on the deleted line or it goes to the rightmost position it can on the next line. (The first GIF below is from Visual Studio Code and the second one is from Atom.)

Is there a way to change this behaviour to be more like Atom?

[image: VSCode delete-line]

[image: Atom delete-line]

Comment: Does Cmd/Ctrl-X do what you want?  Seems to for me.  Then you could set the command editor.action.clipboardCutAction to your keybinding.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of does. But as the name suggests, it cuts the whole line to the clipboard and I can see a scenario where I'd like to keep something else in my clipboard when I trim lines from my code.

Comment: Ahh, good point.  Then I think you would have to make a macro which would be easy or just [Function]-Home the cursor after the line deletion.