# How to customize functionality of "Delete Line" hotkey in Visual Studio Community 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022

In most IDE's I've used, including VS Code, the "Edit.LineDelete" keyboard shortcut deletes the line and tries to keep the cursor in the same place on the following line. For example, this shortcut is Ctrl+Shift+K in VS Code and Ctrl+Y in IntelliJ, and does the following:

```
// I've used a pipe here to represent the cursor movement... 

/* BEFORE line delete */ 
        {
            ... 
            int foo = 0; |
            foo++; 
        }
/* AFTER line delete */ 
        {
            ... 
            int foo = 0;  
            foo++;|
        }
```

However, Visual Studio Community Edition (both 2017 and 2022) seem to have a unique way of handling this. Instead of trying to keep the cursor in the same position, it immediately sends the cursor to the very beginning of the line (even before tab spaces). See the following:

```
/* AFTER line delete on Visual Studio Community */ 
        {
            ... 
            int foo = 0;  
|           foo++;
        }
```

This is extremely annoying for me, as it requires extra work (mouse or End key) to get the cursor back to a useful location. I'm not even sure why they would make this work nicely in VS Code but not VS Community Edition.

Is there a way to change this functionality to mirror the behavior in VS Code or IntelliJ? I don't know of any built-in support for macros, and it seems like overkill to get an extension just for this change. Am I missing something?

NOTE: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49207021/how-to-set-text-cursor-at-beginning-of-new-line-after-deleting-whole-line), but I'm looking to do the exact opposite.

Comment: If you haven't yet, consider submitting this as a suggestion or bug through the VS Feedback system.  This is good feedback for the VS editor team, but they probably won't see it here.

Comment: @Jimmy thank you for the advice -- I just submitted it there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The default shortcut is `Ctrl + Shift + L`
see: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/keyboard-shortcuts.pdf

Comment: The issue here is not with the shortcut (the shortcut you mentioned is what I was using in the second code block above), but with the actual behavior of the command itself. Ctrl + Shift + L causes the cursor to return to the beginning of the line, while VSCode and other editors support a similar "Delete Line" command which essentially functions as a macro for "Delete Line, End", and move the cursor to a more appropriate location on the line.